# Get notification when focused stage changes

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm creating a window menu for JavaFX, similar to the default "Window" menu on OS X. This menu contains a list of windows for the application and uses a checkmark to indicate the currently focussed one.

I'm getting the list of all windows from

```
StageHelper.getStages()
```

which gives me an `ObservableList` to automatically react on removed or newly created windows. What is left is to mark the menu item with the currently focused window. I don't want to actively check for the focused stage as I need to get notified as soon as the focused stage changes.

My current idea would be to add a focus listener to every stage that is created, however I was wondering if there is something else. Is there maybe any helper class that holds an observable property to the currently focused stage?

Comment: Aside: `StageHelper` is private API and it's very strongly recommended not to use it (it won't be accessible in Java 9, for example).

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm looking for a java 8 only solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I very strongly recommend not using non-public API. You're probably better off creating a `StageFactory` class, initializing it with your primary stage, and requesting new stages from it. Then it can keep track of all the stages for you (and can also easily keep track of the focused stage).

If you do want to do things this way, create an `ObservableList<Stage>` with an extractor mapping to the `focusedProperty`, and bind its content to your existing list of stages. Then the new list will fire updates if any focused properties change.

SSCCE:

```
import com.sun.javafx.stage.StageHelper;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TrackFocusedStage extends Application {

    int stageCount = 1 ;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableList<Stage> stages = FXCollections.observableArrayList(stage -> new Observable[] {stage.focusedProperty()});
        Bindings.bindContent(stages, StageHelper.getStages());
        Label label = new Label();
        stages.addListener((Change <? extends Stage> c) -> 
            label.setText(
                    stages.stream()
                    .filter(Stage::isFocused)
                    .findAny()
                    .map(Stage::getTitle)
                    .orElse("")));

        Button newStageButton = new Button("New Window");
        newStageButton.setOnAction(e -> newStage());
        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(new StackPane(newStageButton), label, null, null, null), 300, 180);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Primary");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void newStage() {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Window "+(++stageCount));
        Button close = new Button("Close");
        close.setOnAction(e -> stage.hide());
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(close), 300, 80));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```